# How to emulate GCal's Quick Add string parser

Tags: php, string, forms, parsing, variables

I'd really like to offer my users the ability to type in a single string: "Meet Allison at 6:30 downtown" having my web app pull ou the variables as such:

```
$title="Meet Allison";
$time="0630"; //or unix time, etc.
$location="downtown";
```

All I can think of is to manually parse the string with standard PHP functions, but this feels like the kind of problem someone's already written a nifty php function for.

I've tried googling this several times but I'm having a hard time figuring out what to search exactly. "get different variables from string"? "Parsing string for variables"?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using ruby, I would suggest the 'nickel' gem. It looks like they provide a web service you could probably use, though, if you don't mind that.
http://naturalinputs.com/